# Keep Admin Logged In For a Year

Tags: functions

I would like to keep the admin account logged in for a long time, such as a year. I am using this code:

```
add_filter( ‘auth_cookie_expiration’, ‘keep_me_logged_in_for_1_year’ );

function keep_me_logged_in_for_1_year( $expirein ) {
return 31556926; // 1 year in seconds
}
```

But still I am being logged out in my Chrome browser every so often. Why does this happen?

Comment: Did you check to see if your cookie was still there when it asked you to log in again? If it is, it'll be an issue with the cookie, if not, then the browser or an app might have deleted it.

Comment: how could I identify the cookie ?

Comment: In Chrome: Click on the icon (usually a padlock) to the left of the site's address in the address bar, then click on `Cookies`. Alternatively, go to `chrome://settings/siteData?search=cookies` and search in there.